# Get JSON data from .html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a dynamic html page and I want to pass a string using JSON.

Previously, I have only done this using PHP, eg:

```
$data->pagedata=$pagedata;
echo json_encode($data);
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this client side, with JavaScript or JQuery at all?

The string would be stored within a Javascript Variable. I would want to retrieve that string from another website using JQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to pass a string.. pass a string from where to where?

Comment: @RPM from one website to another. I am presuming I will store the string in a JavaScript varaiable. I have edited the qustion above

Comment: do you mean pass json variable from one client to another client?

Comment: From one page to another page or cross domain, via popup window or request uri?

Answer (score 0):

the JSON is at a particular URL?

If you're using JQUERY, you can use the load() function - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

There is some way doing this

1. If your page 1 call page 2 via window.open, then page 2 can have access to all page 1 js variables via window.parent.{variable name} or window.top.{variable}. This also avaiable when you embed page 2 in iframe in page 1
2. If your page 1 call page 2 via redirect, you can only pass variable via url. Ig: http://www.abc.com/?json={urlencodejson}. Then in page 2 using javascript to retrieve that encoded json.